# Expose port of SSH tunnel that is running inside a docker container

Tags: docker, ssh-tunnel

Inside a docker container I create the following tunnel in an interactive shell:

```
ssh -4 root@remotehost.com -L 8443:127.0.0.1:80
```

In another shell on the same container I can successfully run the following:

```
curl http://localhost:8443
```

The server (remotehost.com) does respond with HTML content.

(Note: I'm using plain HTTP for now to make it easier to debug. In the end I need to be using HTTPS, that's why I choose the local port to be 8443.)

This docker container does expose its port 8443:

```
# docker port be68e57bc3e0
8443/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8443
```

But when I try to connect from the host to that port I get the following:

```
# curl --verbose http://localhost:8443
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8443 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8443
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
* Closing connection 0
```

Here I'm lost. Why doesn't it behave exactly the same way as when connecting from inside the container? Am I misunderstanding something about SSH tunnels?

Comment: How did you run your docker container?. Do you see anything in your server logs?

Comment: @ofirule I only see the first curl call in the logs on remotehost.com but not the second. The container is run using 'docker-compose up -d'.

Comment: If the request is reaching the server I guess it's a server configuration issue, like configuring a looser  `KNOW_HOSTS` or something in this direction

Comment: @ofirule I might not have written it clearly enough: the request is NOT seen in the logs on remotehost.com.

Comment: Ok so my guess is that your server is that the port is not exported from docker correctly, can yo please provide the output of `sudo netstat -nlpt`

Comment: @ofirule I'm on OS X which has a slightly different netstat but the equivalent `netstat -p tcp -van | grep LISTEN` is showing that someone is listening on 8443. Also if I close the tunnel and start `nc -l -p 8443` inside the container, I can `nc 127.0.0.1 8443` to it from the host. So I think the port is indeed exported correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add the `-g` flag to the ssh line that creates the tunnel.